# Image not showing in javascript print preview

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print data to a pre formatted document. Student will answer the questions in text area, when click on print to PDF It will print the answer with school name and logo. Everything working fine but logo is not previewing and printing. I collected the code. Simple HTML and JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

Here is the complete code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0;">
        <h1>Online Test</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Data entry section.-->
    <div id="container_data_entry">
         <h2 id="subject"><b>Subject - Computer Science</b></h2> <br />

        <div id="container" style="width:100%;overflow:auto;">
            <ul>
                <li><b>Q No. 1:</b>Question one?</li>
                <li><textarea id="a1"></textarea></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Q No. 2:</b>Question two?</li>
                <li><textarea id="a2"></textarea></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Q No. 3:</b> Question three?</li>
                <li><textarea id="a3"></textarea></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="button" style="" value="Print to PDF" id="btPrint" onclick="onlineTestApp.printPage();" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let onlineTestApp = new function () {
        this.printPage = function () {
            let style = "<style>";
            style = style + "h1, h2 {text-align:center; font:22px Times New Roman; font-weight:bold;}";
            style = style + ".answers {font:18px Calibri; padding:10px 0;}";
            style = style + "</style>";   
            let header ='<img src="logo.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>' +
            '<h1>School Name</h1>' + '<h2>Online Test</h2>';
            let theBody = '';
            // get all textarea (anwsers).
            let ele_tArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            for (let i = 0; i <= ele_tArea.length - 1; i++) {
                if (theBody === '') {
                    if (ele_tArea[i].value != '') {
                        theBody = '<p class="answers"> <b>Answer ' + (i + 1) + '</b> - ' + ele_tArea[i].value + '</p>';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (ele_tArea[i].value != '') {
                        theBody = theBody + '<p class="answers"> <b>Answer ' + (i + 1) + '</b> - ' + ele_tArea[i].value + '</p>';
                    }
                }
            }
            theBody = header + theBody;
            // Create window object and print the data.
            let  newWin = window.open('', '', '');

            newWin.document.write(style);
            newWin.document.write(theBody);
            newWin.print();
            newWin.close();
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling print before the image has loaded. You can make the function async and add `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))` before your print and it works. I do not know the best way for you to decide to check for the image to have loaded. You could use a while loop and check every 200 ms or so for the image to load.

Here is an example of me testing with a random image from google.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0;">
        <h1>Online Test</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Data entry section.-->
    <div id="container_data_entry">
         <h2 id="subject"><b>Subject - Computer Science</b></h2> <br />

        <div id="container" style="width:100%;overflow:auto;">
            <ul>
                <li><b>Q No. 1:</b>Question one?</li>
                <li><textarea id="a1"></textarea></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Q No. 2:</b>Question two?</li>
                <li><textarea id="a2"></textarea></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Q No. 3:</b> Question three?</li>
                <li><textarea id="a3"></textarea></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="button" style="" value="Print to PDF" id="btPrint" onclick="onlineTestApp.printPage();" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let onlineTestApp = new function () {
        //ADDED ASYNC ⬇
        this.printPage = async function () {
            let style = "<style>";
            style = style + "h1, h2 {text-align:center; font:22px Times New Roman; font-weight:bold;}";
            style = style + ".answers {font:18px Calibri; padding:10px 0;}";
            style = style + "</style>";
            //ADDED TEST LOGO ⬇
            let testLogo = "https://logodix.com/logo/1961524.png";
            let header ='<img src="'+testLogo+'" width="100px" height="100px"/>' +
            '<h1>School Name</h1>' + '<h2>Online Test</h2>';
            let theBody = '';
            // get all textarea (anwsers).
            let ele_tArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            for (let i = 0; i <= ele_tArea.length - 1; i++) {
                if (theBody === '') {
                    if (ele_tArea[i].value != '') {
                        theBody = '<p class="answers"> <b>Answer ' + (i + 1) + '</b> - ' + ele_tArea[i].value + '</p>';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (ele_tArea[i].value != '') {
                        theBody = theBody + '<p class="answers"> <b>Answer ' + (i + 1) + '</b> - ' + ele_tArea[i].value + '</p>';
                    }
                }
            }
            theBody = header + theBody;
            // Create window object and print the data.
            let  newWin = window.open('', '', '');

            newWin.document.write(style);
            newWin.document.write(theBody);
            //ADDED await setTimeout ⬇
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
            newWin.print();
            newWin.close();
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have understood it. I t's working now. It's loading to new tab then can print. Can i use AJAX to pre load the image and can print from this window?